# Observables does not update values

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, internet-explorer-11

Ajax call will only execute once, and then it's like ie caching the response and therefore my observables hold old values.

**The code looks like this:**

```
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("GetInfo", "Info")",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { id: newSelection },
            async: false,
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.success) {
                    var array = [];
                    var existing = [];
                    $.each(response.data, function (index, value) {
                        array.push(value);
                        existing.push(value)
                    });


                    self.myObservable(array);
                    self.myObservable2(existing);

                } else {
                    alert(response.message);
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

How come that this code works perfectly in firefox and chrome but not ie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution [here](http://www.itworld.com/development/303295/ajax-requests-not-executing-or-updating-internet-explorer-solution)

The problem is that IE automaticly caching ajax responses that use GET as method, while firefox and chrome doesn't.

My solution was to add cache: false in the ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `ko.cleanNode` when leaving the page?

Example:

```
$(document).on("pagehide", function()
{
     ko.cleanNode(document);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. No i haven't tried that, but will do that now. :) It is strange that my code works perfectly in firefox and chrome but not IE.

Comment: Can't say I'm surprised, IE is always causing me issues.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("pagehide", function () {
        ko.cleanNode(document);
    });              this didnt help. :( Damn IE...